# Running curl commads in a loop while reading from a file in bash

Tags: bash, for-loop, curl

I'm trying to parse a file by line and then trying to run all the curl commands in it, and then logging the successful v/ unsuccessful calls.

```
cat file 

/usr/bin/curl  -X POST http://localhost/services/migration -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'cache-control: no-cache' -d ' [{"resources": [{"name": "Provisioned Throughput (at peek load)","value": "514"}],"entityTypes": [{"app": "thanos"}],"subEntityTypes": [{"vapps": "loki-odinson"}],"user": "foobar@tt.com"}]';
/usr/bin/curl  -X POST http://localhost/services/migration -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'cache-control: no-cache' -d ' [{"resources": [{"name": "Provisioned Throughput (at peek load)","value": "5124"}],"entityTypes": [{"app": "stark"}],"subEntityTypes": [{"vapps": "tony-s"}],"user": "foobar@tt.com"}]';
```

I am parsing the file by line. echo statement works fine and gives me curl command, but when I try to run it plainly, it gives me -bash: No such file or directory error.

I could source the whole file but that would be a pain in logging to see how many failed vs succeeded.

Below is the command im trying to run.

```
IFS=$'\n'
for var in `cat ten`; do $var ; sleep 1 ; done
```

Comment: Check the [BashFAQ](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).

Answer (score 1):

To run each command listed in a file called commands.txt, simply treat it as a script: `bash commands.txt`.

That said, the loop has several issues:

1. Overriding `IFS` globally is going to cause some weird behaviour. Basically you'll only ever want to override it for a single command, as in `IFS=$'\n' COMMAND`.
2. [Use `$(COMMAND)` instead of backticks](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082).
3. [Don't loop over lines using `for`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).
4. You'll want to [put a command into an array](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) to handle non-trivial arguments (such as those containing whitespace).

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a trap.

```
$:  cat x
trap 'echo "$BASH_COMMAND">>errs' ERR
echo 1 2 3 4
bogus 5 6 7 8
true this one
false this one
$: ./x
1 2 3 4
bash: bogus: command not found
$: cat errs
bogus 5 6 7 8
false this one
./x
```

`errs` is now the list of the ones that failed. `grep -vf errs x` to get the ones that succeeded. (Will include the trap.)